# Is there a way to watch an apps network activity?

Tags: macos

With all the news about companies being hacked, is there a way to monitor a specific software's network traffic? Even on the Apple app store and Google Android app store there were apps sending user data without user's permission.

Answer (score 0):

The most well known package sniffer (for Windows and Mac OS): [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)

Android: try [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555403/capturing-mobile-phone-traffic-on-wireshark)

Linux: try [this](https://superuser.com/questions/23180/whats-the-easiest-way-to-sniff-tcp-traffic-data-on-linux)

iOS: There is no way without exploiting bugs and hacking the operation system.